# Installing Tomcat 7 using apt-get fails

Tags: apt, dpkg, tomcat

I get the following error when installing Tomcat7:

```
Setting up tomcat7 (7.0.26-1ubuntu1.1) ...  
chmod: cannot access `/etc/tomcat7/tomcat-users.xml': No such file or directory  
dpkg: error processing tomcat7 (--configure):  
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1  
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already  

 >Errors were encountered while processing:  
 tomcat7  
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And I get this error when I try to apt-get remove Tomcat7:

```
Removing tomcat7 ...  
 * tomcat7 is not installed  
invoke-rc.d: initscript tomcat7, action "stop" failed.
```

How do I fix this to install Tomcat 7 correctly?

Comment: Try to run a `apt-get purge tomcat7` and reinstall it. See if it helps. I just wonder why you would like to use the deb package from official repository, for Tomcat, I'd rather download the binary and extract it (chown) and run as a normal user. If you want it to start during boot, there are plenty of options out there.

Comment: Running apt-get purge tomcat7 did not work. Whoever when I removed all the tomcat7 optional tomcat7 packages like tomcat7-admin, it finally worked.

Comment: Terry, I like the way the packaged version is installed on the file system. My tomcat configurations files are under /etc and my log files under /var/log etc. What I do not like about the package is it's dependency on OpenJDK, I prefer using the Oracle JDK.

Comment: I understand your concern. To install Oracle JDK, there is an easy script on github, please check this out: http://askubuntu.com/questions/213583/not-recognize-jdk-after-installation-in-ubuntu-12-10/213590#213590

Comment: i am smiling :)

Comment: The packaged tomcat7 does not depend on OpenJDK. It depends on _a_ Java. The exact specification is `default-jre-headless | java6-runtime-headless | java6-runtime | java-6-runtime`. You can use the packaged tomcat7 with the Oracle JDK.

Comment: is this still reproducible, I couldn't.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact the same problem.

I had to run this command (see below) to see what all tomcat related libraries are there and remove ALL the tomcat related libraries:

To see what all tomcat related libraries are there:

```
dpkg -l | grep -i tomcat
```

To remove a tomcat library:

```
dpkg -P <library-name>
```

Then, I reinstalled tomcat7 using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```

[ During installation, it spit out messages saying it is going to install some of the other libraries related to tomcat7 - I chose - yes ].

It installed tomcat7 and started it.

Then, I stopped and restarted tomcat7 using these commands:

```
/etc/init.d/tomcat7 stop
/etc/init.d/tomcat7 start
```

Answer (score 1):

I had error stated that `tomcat7 is aready newer version`.
Steps :

1. Uninstall `tomcat7` using command `sudo apt-get
   autoremove tomcat7`.
2. This uninstalls `tomcat7` completely.
3. Now install it using `sudo apt-get install tomcat7`.

It worked well with me, give it a try.

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with the question at hand. Could you maybe clarify?

Comment: @Seth : The question is **tomcat7** installation fails using **apt-get** method, so I suggested the possible solution that I have tried and got desired result.
If I have miss-understood this question, kindly let me know :)

Answer (score -1):

Run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge libtomcat7-java tomcat6 tomcat6-admin tomcat6-docs tomcat6-examples tomcat7 tomcat7-admin tomcat7-common tomcat7-docs tomcat7-examples tomcat7-user

sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```